# .htaccess issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, trailing-slash

In my site the URL

1) *http://www.example.com/pt-br/perguntas-frequentes/* - shows error

2) *http://www.example.com/pt-br/perguntas-frequentes*  -  working fine.

I am using WPML plugin
Code as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: tripadvisorsuccess.com/pt-br/perguntas-frequentes - error tripadvisorsuccess.com/pt-br/perguntas-frequentes - error to! Can you post working page? End currant .htaccess